# Picking up good values for a temperature program

Tags: c++, vector

I'm studying C++ by 2 months using the book : Programming principles and practice using C++. Now I'm reading the chapter about errors, and in a section the author speaks of logic errors. Before using a program as an example, and then a revised version to understand the error. This is the first program :

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
// find the highest, lowest and averega temperature
int main()
{

vector<double> temps;

for (double temp; cin >> temp;)
temps.push_back(temp);

  double sum = 0;
  double high_temp = 0;
  double low_temp = 0;

for (double x : temps)
{
if (x > high_temp) high_temp = x;
if (x < low_temp) low_temp = x;
sum += x;
}

 cout << "Highest temperature : " << high_temp << '\n';
 cout << "Lowest temperature : " << low_temp << '\n';
 cout << "Average temperature : " << sum / temps.size() << '\n';


}
```

As you can see if I enter, for example, a set of temperatures relating to the month of August I will get wrong ouput results because I will enter just positive values but low_temp will remain 0.0 unless one of the temperatures in the data was below zero (impossible in summer !).

So the author revised this program :

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{

 vector<double> temps;

 double high_temp = -1000; // initialize to impossibly low 
 double low_temp = 1000; // initialize to impossibly high 
 double sum = 0; 
 int no_of_temps = 0; 

 for (double temp; cin >> temp;) {
 ++no_of_temps; 
sum += temp; 

if (temp > high_temp) high_temp = temp; 
if (temp < low_temp) low_temp = temp; 

 }

cout << "Highest temperature : " << high_temp << '\n';
cout << "Lowest temperature : " << low_temp << '\n';
cout << "Average temperature : " << sum / no_of_temps<< '\n';


}
```

My problem lies in the exercise that the author asks me to do :

> Look it up. Check some information sources to pick good values for the min_temp("the minimum temperaure") and max_temp("the maximum temperature") constants of our program. Those values will determine the usefulness of our program.

What does you mean the author with this exercise? the program still needs some improvements in your opinion? What values you would give to min_temp and max_temp ? What are the problems related to the solution used to write such a program ?

Comment: I guess the question should be for `min_temp` and `max_temp` as constants, because `low_temp` and `high_temp` are used to store variable data? EDIT: though I'm not sure what limits could be used for, as they would distort the analysis by clamping `temp` to a valid range ...

Comment: Well.. Highest temperature can always be initialized at 0°K (-273.15°C)

Answer (score 0):

You should start with such constants such that the first comparison will always succeed. Picking +/-1000 is OK, but then you're artificially limiting yourself when you don't have to. A better solution might be to pick constants that are definitely at the extremes:

```
double high_temp = -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
double low_temp = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
```

Any temperature you enter will be higher than `-inf` and lower than `inf`, so that comparison will succeed and do the right thing.

Comment: the use of the values 1000 and -1000 is a example of "magic constants" ? and if so, why ?